# My OBD 2 port is completely shredded, need help with wiring!

Tags: wiring, diagram

The harness of my OBD2 female is shredded but the wires are still intact. I got a new female port but I failed to find a proper wiring diagram to help me align the wires to their respective output in my CADILLAC STS 2005 (for eg. the red and white wire goes to slot 16 which is the power source). Here are the wires that are dangling (but the red and white one is still intact with slot 16 hence i know about it).
Black,
Black and white,
Orange,
Orange and black,
Green,
Red and White (battery)

If someone could please tell me which of these wires correspond to which slot or just the circuit numbers of these wires could help too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Pinout picture]

1. D-GN Low Speed GMLAN Serial Data

2–3. Not Used

4. BK Ground
5. BK/WH Ground
6. TN/BK High Speed GMLAN Serial Data (+) (1)

7–13. Not Used

14. TN High Speed GMLAN Serial Data (-) (1)
15. Not Used
16. RD/WH Battery Positive Voltage

Comment: https://www.freeasestudyguides.com/electrical-troubleshooting-data-link-connector.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Model specfic image of your DLC pinout, It also has color codes.

[image]